# Which is better, Using multiple column in GROUP BY or GROUP BY with AGGREGATE?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Hotel table like,

```
hotelId  | hotelName  | city
=============================
h1       |   name1    | city1
h1       |   name1    | city2
h2       |   name2    | city3
h2       |   name2    | city4
h3       |   name3    | city5
h4       |   name3    | city6
```

If I want to query unique `hotelId and name` (`HotelId and HotelName will always be same`), which is better query?

**Using Multiple Group By**

```
Select hotelId, hotelName from Hotel 
Group By HotelId, HotName
```

**Using Group By With Aggregate**

```
Select HotelId, Max(hotelName) from Hotel
Group By HotelId
```

Comment: It depends on what you want as output. if you want to get hotel name displayed with count as output, go with first one or else second one.

Comment: In both cases, HotelName will be displayed

Comment: Why don't you use SELECT DISTINCT  HotelId, HotelName FROM Hotel ?

Comment: Yes, best solution is to use DISTINCT. Why use GROUP BY in first place?

Comment: I know, DISTINCT will be better, but I want to know which one is good among those two?

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
select distinct hotelId, hotelname from hotel
```

Answer (score 0):

i feel OP is asking on performance point of view is`t it OP? if it is then:

As no need to tell here both above query(OP) serves different purpose, but in some cases like in your case we can use aggregate function like you use here MAX(). to serve the purpose. if you look into execution plan you might see hash aggregate with little cost. so your second query is better. performance will be visible with huge data try yourself with example.

now i come to choosing distinct or group by all columns
as far as performance point of view both will generate identical plan, but distinct is short cut to group all column.